# Updating IP routing table with iOS

Tags: ios, network-programming, cfnetworking

Is there a way to programmatically have an iOS app add an entry into your network's routing table? Perhaps via CFNetwork?

Basically, the equivalent of this command:

```
$ route add -host
```

Comment: Add to your iOS device or your network router's?